# generate random words from a table to insert into another table( PLSQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql

Table with word I want to generate

```
create table words
( word varchar(100));

insert into words values ('Main street');
insert into words values ('Patrick Street');
insert into words values ('Red Street');
insert into words values ('Green street');
insert into words values ('Blue street');
insert into words values ('Yellow street');
insert into words values ('Silver street');
insert into words values ('Gold street');
insert into words values ('Brown street');
```

PLSQL code for insert

```
    declare  
randTemp number(10); 
tempCounty VARCHAR(20); 
streetaddress VARCHAR(100);
Begin 
For i in 1..9 
Loop 
randTemp := dbms_random.value(1,5);
SELECT c.countyname INTO tempCounty FROM county C WHERE c.countyid = randTemp;
SELECT w.word INTO streetaddress FROM words w ORDER BY dbms_random.random limit 1; 
Insert into BRANCH values(i,streetaddress,tempCounty,randTemp); 
End loop; 
Commit; 
End; 
/
```

Everything works besides this select statement

```
SELECT w.word INTO streetaddress FROM words w ORDER BY dbms_random.random limit 1;
```

I get this error

ORA-06550: line 10, column 75:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I think the limit might be the problem...???

Answer (score 1):

You're right, `limit` is the problem because that is not something Oracle supports.

You can do something like this instead:

```
SELECT word INTO streetaddress
FROM (
    SELECT word
    FROM words
    ORDER BY dbms_random.random
)
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

The inner query is ordering the potential words randomly, and the out query uses the `rownum` pseudocolumn to pick the first one returned, similar to what `limit` would do.

Repeating that query in a loop doesn't seem very efficient though; you might be better off doing something like:

```
DECLARE
    tempCounty VARCHAR(20);
    streetaddress VARCHAR2(100);
    cur sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR
        SELECT word, countyname
        FROM (
            SELECT w.word, c.countyname
            FROM words w
            CROSS JOIN county c
            ORDER BY dbms_random.random
        )
        WHERE rownum <= 9;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO streetaddress, tempCounty;
        EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(streetaddress ||', '|| tempCounty);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

That is, generating all possible combinations of the fields from the two tables, ordering that randomly, and restricting it to the first 9 results.

But it depends what you're dong with it - if you're simply populating another table as the question suggests, then you can use that kind of query as part of a `insert into ... select ...` construct, avoiding PL/SQL and loops entirely:

```
INSERT INTO branch
SELECT rownum, word, countyname, countyid
FROM (
    SELECT w.word, c.countyname, c.countyid
    FROM words w
    CROSS JOIN county c
    ORDER BY dbms_random.random
)
WHERE rownum <= 9;
```

If you're doing more processing in PL/SQL and have a lot of rows then using `bulk collect` might speed things up further.

Comment: LIMIT is being introduced in 12c, apparently.